# Evaluate the following path of the integral: $\int_{λ}(Re\:z)^2dz$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

Evaluate the following path of the integral:
$$\int_{λ}(Re\:z)^2dz$$
where $λ_1 = [z_0, z_1]$ (the straight-line path connecting $z_0$ and $z_1$).

Ive been trying to evaluate this integral for quite a while which is a small part of a project ive been working on. Any help towards the answer will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** With $\lambda:\, z(t)=(1-t)z_0+tz_1$; $0\leq t\leq1$, we have
$$\int_{λ}({\bf Re}\,z)^2dz=\int_0^1((1-t)x_0+tx_1)^2(z_1-z_0)dt$$
where $x_0={\bf Re}\,z_0$ and $x_1={\bf Re}\,z_1$.

Comment: I don't thik so since $dz$ factor is complex.

Comment: So is this hint correct?? @StevenStadnicki

Comment: Is this hint correct? @MyGlasses

Comment: Well I guess not since since you stated it above @MyGlasses

Comment: So we await for a referee!

Comment: MyGlasses: You should tell us what $x_0,x_1$ are.

Comment: @B.Smith How could it not be correct? The only thing being used is the parameterization of a line segment and the definition of a contour integral.